# How can I share a ViewModel between Activities?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I have two classes, `MainActivity` and `RegisterActivity`. Into the latter you can enter name, age, and phone number. After typing in that information I store it in a `ViewModel` (i.e. `RegisterActivity` *has-a* `ViewModel`) and click a button to finish the `RegisterActivity`. The thing is, I want to access the data stored in the model from within `MainActivity`.

So how can I share the `ViewModel` between the two activities? What concept do I have to use?

Comment: you can't share viewmodel between activities. and also, in this case, I think it's an antipattern. use `startActivityForResult` and `setResult` to pass this kind of data.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can't share a ViewModel across Activities. That's specifically one of the downsides of using multiple activities as per the [Single Activity talk](https://youtu.be/2k8x8V77CrU?t=344).

Comment: If i want to share the data between activities,  are there both using Intet.puExtra and Android jetpack Navigation?

Comment: There's an absolutely huge difference between what you can do with a shared ViewModel and what you can do with Intent extras. `startActivityForResult()` / the [Activity Result API](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) both certainly work from any Fragment, whether you are using Navigation or not.

Answer (score 4):

viewModel cannot be directly shared between activities however, if u store viewmodelfactory in application class and retrieve factory object from activities and access viewmodel then u can share state of view model, i checked this senario in featureModule app, it worked

Comment: Can you provide the GitHub code or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the data you want to keep for the MainActivity into your Application class or use SharedPreferences.

Comment: What do you mean by "Application class"? I argue that SharedPreferences is out of scope for OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel has application level lifecycle. If you use single viewmodel with two or more activities then after attaching with first activity when it get attached with other one. then there might be some problem.

Comment: Please update your answer with proper information and possibly with some code samples for reference. Like, what will be the problems and what can be the possible solution of it etc.

Answer (score -1):

What @ianhanniballake said is true, but it doesn't mean that you can't do something to solve this type of problem.
You can use Koin for example to create a solution. I did something that helped me to deal with this:

https://gist.github.com/jeancsanchez/0d2fe3c677330e335f5740bcd5b3ca29

It creates a scope for the main activity and the other one can get the same ViewModel instance with the same scope.