# How to create a global progress dialog that can handle multiple asynchronous tasks

Tags: android, kotlin, progressdialog

I have a base fragment where I added the method below that will show a progress dialog, on some occasions multiple async methods will start at the same time and all of them will be calling the showProgressDialog method, and so I'm facing the following problems:

- the methods that call for showProgressDialog are not connected and not fixed, some of them might get called and some might not and they don't run in a specific order, depending on many user conditions.
- if one of the methods that called the progress dialog failed it needs to show an error dialog, but other methods will stay running until they either finish or fail.

to solve the first problem I created a counter called showNo which will get incremented when a method wants to show the progress dialog, and decremented when the method finishes and wants to hide it, this way the progress dialog will get hidden only when all running methods finish. but this also cause another problem as it very hard to track and if you the method showing progress dialog doesn't get the correct showNo the progress dialog will stay on the screen for ever.

```
    fun showProgressDialog(show: Boolean) {
    if (!show && dialog != null) {
        showNo--
        if (showNo <= 0) {
            dialog!!.dismiss()
            showNo = 0
        }
        return
    } else if (!show && dialog == null) {
        return
    }
    if (showNo <= 0 && context != null) {
        val binding: DialogProgressBinding =
            DialogProgressBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()), null, false)
        dialog = Dialog(requireContext())
        dialog!!.apply {
            setContentView(binding.root)
            setCancelable(false)
            window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            dismiss()
            show()
        }
    }
    showNo++
}
```

this is the method I created to show the dialog, but I need a better approach that is more usable

Comment: What is your progress dialog showing?

Comment: @blackapps just a custom progress bar with some text

Comment: Are you using coroutines? Does your app support screen rotation?

Comment: yes, I'm using coroutines, there's no screen rotation support, only portrait

Comment: Just a custom progressbar? What does it ,indicate? What is maximum? To how much does it count? Pretty unclear for what you use a progressbar. You never told. You should have started with it.

Comment: @blackapps that's irrelevant to my question, you can think about it as the default rotating progress layout that comes with android without any number indicator or any extra stuff

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create a shared `ViewModel` that all your `Fragment`s can access, say through your Activity's `ViewModelProvider` or one for your current navigation graph (if you're using the `ktx` version of the `viewmodel` library you can create these with `val model: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()` or `by navGraphViewModels()`)

That way you can have one central component that's responsible for tracking the current state of what should be displayed, and UI components (say one of your `Fragment`s, or the containing `Activity`) can `observe` a `LiveData` exposing that state, and display any dialogs as required.

---

It's probably a good idea to create an `enum` that represents the possible states:

```
enum class DisplayState {
    NONE, PROGRESS, ERROR, PROGRESS_AND_ERROR
}
```

Or maybe a sealed class, so you can give the different states properties:

```
sealed class DisplayState {
    data class Progress(val progressAmount: Int) : DisplayState()
    data class Error(errorMessage: String) : DisplayState()
    data class ProgressAndError(val progressAmount: Int, val errorMessage: String): DisplayState()
}
```

Or maybe just a combo state object:

```
// If a thing isn't null, display it!
// Null default values make it easy to say exactly what state you want,
// e.g. DisplayState(errorMessage = "oh nos") is just an error message
data class DisplayState(
    val progressAmount: Int? = null,
    val errorMessage: String? = null
)
```

And now you can expose that state in a VM:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // using the "combo" version above
    private val _displayState = mutableLiveData(DisplayState())
    // observe this to see the current state, and any updates to it
    val displayState: LiveData<DisplayState> get() = _displayState
}
```

and the observer in the UI layer can show or hide dialogs as necessary.

---

Since everything's coordinated through this one `ViewModel` instance, it can keep track of things like how many clients have requested a particular dialog is shown. This part's a bit tricky because it depends what you want - if two different callers request a progress dialog at different times or with different amounts of progress, how much progress do you display? Does that change if the caller with the displayed progress cancels its dialog request?

If so, you'll need to keep track of which callers have ongoing requests and what their individual state (e.g. progress) is, e.g. by putting them in a `Map`. (You could use a `WeakHashMap` to avoid holding `Fragment`s in memory, but I wouldn't recommend it - I'll get to that in a minute.) Otherwise, a counter is probably fine? Depending on how you're doing *async* stuff you might need some thread-safe synchronisation.

Here's one way you could do it, using caller references:

```
// in the VM
val progressDialogRequesters = mutableSetOf<Any>()

fun requestProgressDialog(caller: Any) {
    progressDialogRequesters += caller
    // you could be smarter here and e.g. only call it if the set was empty before
    updateDisplayState()
}

fun cancelProgressDialog(caller: Any) {
    progressDialogRequesters -= caller
    // again you could do this only if the set is now empty
    updateDisplayState()
}

// also similar error ones

private fun updateDisplayState() {
    // here you want to push a new state depending on the current situation
    // with -all- requests and any state they have (e.g. progress amounts).
    // Just doing really simple "if there's a request, show it" logic here
    _displayState.value = DisplayState(
        progressAmount = if (progressDialogRequesters.isEmpty()) null else 50,
        errorMessage = if (errorDialogRequesters.isEmpty()) null else "UH OH"
    )
}
```

---

If you're doing it that way, you could have `Set`s holding references to `Fragment`s etc, potentially keeping them in memory. Using weak references like a `WeakHashMap` can avoid that - but *really*, what you want is a robust system where you *explicitly cancel requests* when you don't need them anymore, either because some task has finished, or because the `Fragment` or whatever is being destroyed. You don't want to rely on the system cleaning up after you, if that makes sense - it can make it harder to track down why things aren't lining up, why your counts are higher than you expected, etc.

It's a little more complicated than that - it really depends how your individual tasks are running, if they're part of a `Fragment` (and die with it or its `viewLifecycleScope`, e.g. if the device is rotated) or if they're more independent. You'll want to store the task itself as its own reference, if you can. But this is another example of why you probably want to coordinate all this through the `ViewModel`, rather than running it as part of the UI Layer. If the VM starts all your tasks, it can keep track of what's running, what's finished and so on. The UI layer just sends events like "start this type of task" and displays the current state. I can only be really general here though because it depends what you're doing. Hope this helps you work something out!

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what if the calls to show the progress dialog are coming from multiple fragments (mainly 2) that each has it independent viewModel?

Comment: @amm965 the point of this approach is it's a shared VM! So they're all talking to the same component that's managing what's going on, and they're all observing the same state so they can display what's currently happening in the VM. If they're all in the same `Activity`, either use `by activityViewModels()` or pass the Activity in your `ViewModelProviders()` call (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing - if you switch between the Kotlin and Java tabs you can see the two ways of accessing it - both work in Kotlin)

Comment: That way everything's fetching the same `ViewModel` instance - the one the `Activity` is using, so all its `Fragment`s can grab their parent's VM and see and interact with the same thing. But it won't work for *multiple Activities* (straight from one of the devs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62845254 ). Also remember, you can have as many `ViewModel`s as you want - just because your Fragments are sharing the Activity's `ProgressViewModel` doesn't mean they can't have their own private `SomethingElseViewModel` that handles other things. Separate stuff into their own components if it makes sense!